# Vertically align items across columns in fluidRow

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shiny application that includes a `fluidRow` with 4 columns. Each column has three items:

1. A subheading (`h4(...)`)
2. An image (`img(...)`) or slider (`sliderInput(...)`)
3. Two rows of text (`textOutput(...)`)

```r
  fluidRow(
    column(
      3,
      h4("Flat Terrain"),
      
      img(src = "walk-flat-terrain.png",
          style = "height:150px;"),
      
      textOutput(outputId = "eg1_uphill"),
      textOutput(outputId = "eg1_downhill")
    ),

    column(
      3,
      h4("2.86° Slope (1:20 Gradient)"),
      
      img(src = "casual-walk.png",
          style = "height:150px;"),
      
      textOutput(outputId = "eg2_uphill"),
      textOutput(outputId = "eg2_downhill"),
    ),

    column(
      3,
      h4("20° Slope"),
      
      img(src = "uphill-slope.png",
          style = "height:150px;"),
      
      textOutput(outputId = "eg3_uphill"),
      textOutput(outputId = "eg3_downhill")
    ),


    column(
      3,
      h4("What about..."),
      
      # 200px height, same as the illustrations
      div(
        style = "height:200px;margin: auto;",

        sliderInput(
        inputId = "custom_slope",
        label = "Slope (degree)",
        min = 0, max = 45, step = .1,
        value = 5,
        width = "80%")
      ),
      
      textOutput(outputId = "custom_uphill"),
      textOutput(outputId = "custom_downhill")
    )
  )
```

The output of the shiny app is like below.

[image: items-unaligned]

The problem is the items are not vertically aligned now. I would like to align the items between the columns, just like a table with 3 rows and 4 columns, and each item is placed inside a "cell".

[image: items-aligned-view]

I tried to move each item to a separate `fluidRow` (i.e. there are three `fluidRow`, with each row storing each item). However, the items will not be in order for narrower window width.

[image: items-not-in-order]